# Resolving circular dependencies in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I keep learning Spring Boot and met a problem with circular dependencies. I have a bot with following structure:

[image]

**Bold** font = class, @Component; **Red bold** = @Dependecy Injection (all via constructors)

I will get an Update from User, then this Update goes to main handler (UpdateReceiver), etc. I see that I need Bot bean almost everywhere (to send messages), but Bot requires UpdateReceiver, because I don't want to handle update in main class, just redirect it:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        //log
        updateReceiver.handleUpdate(update);
    }
```

So, get cycle dependencies. How can I solve this case? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

**Bot class:**

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class AssistantBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    ...

    private UpdateReceiver updateReceiver;

    public AssistantBot(UpdateReceiver updateReceiver) {
        this.updateReceiver = updateReceiver;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        updateReceiver.handleUpdate(update);
    }

    ...

    public synchronized void sendTextMessage(long chatId, String message) {
        SendMessage textMessage = new SendMessage()
                .enableMarkdown(false)
                .setChatId(chatId)
                .setText(message);
        try {
            execute(textMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
other methods to send messages
```

**UpdateReceiver:**

```
@Service
public class UpdateReceiver {

    private TextMessageHandler textMessageHandler;
    private CallbackQueryHandler callbackQueryHandler;
    private AssistantBot bot;


    public UpdateReceiver(TextMessageHandler textMessageHandler,
                          CallbackQueryHandler callbackQueryHandler,
                          AssistantBot bot){
        this.textMessageHandler = textMessageHandler;
        this.callbackQueryHandler = callbackQueryHandler;
        this.bot = bot;
    }

    public void handleUpdate(Update update) {
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()){
            textMessageHandler.handleTextMessage(update);
        }
        else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
            callbackQueryHandler.handleCallbackQuery(update.getCallbackQuery());
        }
        else {
            bot.sendTextMessage(update.getMessage().getChatId(),
                    "I can't handle this!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show minimal  example of `Bot` and `UpdateReceiver` classes (Remove all methods that don't use the other. All the other classes in your diagram are irrelevant

Comment: Added examples of these classes!

Comment: Change `handleUpdate` to return a value. Only have `bot` ever call `handleUpdate`. Process value in `onUpdateReceived`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped! Now I have not best desired design, but still good one.